# Pythonic way to Create a List Comprehension with no Returned Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a dictionary and an array of values to append to it:

```
df = [{'name':'Bob','number':65}, {'name':'Jonh','number':44}]
foo = ['grandpa', 'dad']
```

`df` is my dict and `foo` is an array of values that I want to append to `df` (one value for each dictionary item)

For doing this, I have created a list comprehension:

```
_ = [d.update({'id':f}) for d,f inzip(df, foo)]
```

This of course doesn't return anything but instead update `df`, so my question is: is this the most pythonic way of doing this? Maybe as it doesn't return any value using a for loop will be a better choice, what do you think?

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension if you're not trying to create a list. Use a for-loop. That's what it's for.

Comment: To add on to @khelwood point. It is also a waste of memory.

Comment: I'd say that is the most un-pythonic way you could have come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension is completely inappropriate if you're not trying to make a list.  Instead you're relying on side effects.  Pythonic means explicit is better than implicit, so just convert your code to an explicit `for` loop.

```
for d,f in zip(df, foo):
    d.update({'id':f})
```

Comment: May as well switch to `d['id'] = f`; only reason they were using `d.update` was to make it a legal expression (at the cost of needing to invoke a method rather than simple assignment, and constructing a ton of pointless one-element temporary `dict`s).

Comment: @ShadowRanger true enough, but I like to change as little as I can from the question so that the answer is more understandable to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You would better add them with a loop (i select max(len) in case foo and df are not of the same length):

```
for i in range(max(len(foo), len(df))):
    df[i]['id']=foo[i]
```

Or you can use zip like below (as @ShadowRanger suggested):

```
for d,f in zip(df, foo): 
    d['id'] = f
```

Comment: I'd stick to using `zip`; as written, you're pointlessly looking up each value, `df` and `foo` are both required to be sequences (or mappings, but the OP clearly isn't using them), not arbitrary iterables and mismatched lengths result in an `IndexError` (which might be okay, but it's unusual to invite it).

Comment: `for d,f in zip(df, foo): d['id'] = f` doesn't cover it? It would with normal things (can't speak to dataframes, but it would be odd if indexing and iterating didn't match up).

Comment: Yes you are right, i added it in my solution, thanks